# Use of Javascript with Dojo/Dijit on a WordPress page

Tags: javascript

I just created a web page that uses a lot of JavaScript to build a fancy form that helps build an build the object/html behind an mp3 player for a user.  I got it working and tested in a plain-html page outside of WordPress.

I then copied into a WordPress "page", took out the <head> tag, changed <body> to a <div>, but no luck.

Can it even be done?

I also want to use a small javascript to open up a video-player in a new small browser-window.

Working on raw html page: 
http://learnhowtoputaudioonyoursite.com/TestMP3Player.html

Not working in WP page: 
http://learnhowtoputaudioonyoursite.com/build-player

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Here's a WordPress post that uses canvas, and Dojo / Dijit (side and bottom sliders).

http://pp19dd.com/2010/10/canvas-sine-wave/

Comment: I looked at the code there, but it's hard to tell what was put in the WP Page vs the theme. Do I have to change my theme to do it?   I put my pages in orig post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be much better off [creating a custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), pasting your HTML into the file, then simply attaching the template to a page in the admin.

WordPress applies a lot of filtering on post/page *content*, and it's probably wreaking havoc with your code (not to mention you've got things there that belong in the `<head />`).

**UPDATE:** Create a PHP file in your theme folder (name it template-something.php);

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template Something
*/
?>

<!-- any PHP & HTML goes here!! -->
<!-- Note: Should be a complete HTML document if not calling get_header() -->
```

Comment: Ok, trusting this is best answer.  Sounds like a few hours of research...

Comment: @NealWaters, not at all. See my revised answer!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - Yea, right! Thanks, I am very technical, but this is new ground.  I renamed my .html page to .php, added the php tag at top/bottom, put an "echo" with a heredoc on all my HTML  (also tried no PHP tag). I created a new page in WP, and set it's parent to my new template, and put "What will happen here" in the page-contents. When I view, only "What will happen here" shows (but correctly in the theme with header/sidebar).  Nada, not even the H1 from the template is showing.  Still don't understand how/where it merges the head/body with the parent theme.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - Let me look further, I think I picked the wrong item from the list, and my new template is not on the list...

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - Ok, I didn't realize the comment was actually important!  Got the page to come up, but now with none of the theme.  Which I could have basically done by linking to an .html or .php page.  So now, I presume, the goal will be to put the theme elements back in, by copying/pasting from some other template.

Comment: Yep - at least two hours... http://learnhowtoputaudioonyoursite.com/template-test/  @TheDeadMedic - Had to learn about templates, custom-header: get_header("DijitClaro");  and body_class("claro");  and still have to work on some issues of a table not lining up.  A lot of precedence of CSS issues I presume.

Comment: "Ok, I didn't realize the comment was actually important!" I wouldn't have put it there if it wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

See the following article by wordpress on registering scripts into Wordpress so that they can be used and loaded. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

> wp_enqueue_script( 
>        $handle
>       ,$src
>       ,$deps
>       ,$ver
>       ,$in_footer  );

Especially helpful as Wordpress is biased toward JQuery. Hope this helps.

Comment: How exactly does that solve the question?