# Unwanted line break before <input>

Tags: javascript, formatting, line-breaks

Based on help here (
[Use of Javascript with Dojo/Dijit on a WordPress page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21508/use-of-javascript-with-dojo-dijit-on-a-wordpress-page)) I got Dijit half way working using a custom template.

But, I still can't figure out why WP inserts breaks where it does. I'd like to keep as much of the page in the WP Page, and as little in the template as possible.  Worst case, I guess I do it all in a template.  Right now, I have the header in the template, and the form-stuff in the page.

Specifically, why doesn't Width and the textbox for Width show up on the same line (all browsers)?

What I typed in (I put it all one big long line to try to avoid the breaks):

```
<label for="controlWidth">Width:</label><input type="text" name="controlWidth" value="99" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" trim="true" id="controlWidth" propercase="false" style="width: 50px">
```

What WP puts out:

```
<p>        <label for="controlWidth">Width:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="controlWidth" value="99" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" trim="true" id="controlWidth" propercase="false" style="width: 50px">
```

Secondly, the ColorPalatte looke good in IE, but not FireFox 5 nor Chrome 12.

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug in `wpautop()` which treated `<input>` as a block element. It is fixed now. See ticket [#16456](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16456).